# FIle is open in another application,Process Explorer and similar tools not work

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

So I am trying to delete a file in C:\windows\system32\drivers, and windows keep saying"File is open in another application." After some googling, I tried to use Resource Monitor and Process Explorer to search handle ,and I got **ZERO MATCHING ITEMS**. I'm so frustrated about this issue.

Comment: What is there that you need to delete?  This is normally not a user folder

Comment: I suspect that the System process has a handle given the location as it's most likely a driver. It would be helpful to say what the filename is, to know which service/driver it is.  Can the service be stopped, is it a file system filter etc, maybe it can be unloaded.

Comment: If it's a driver you want to delete, you should probably uninstall it through **Device Manager**.

Comment: Windows doesn't track this info on local files completely because it is turned off for speed reasons. Type in a command prompt `openfiles /local on` (then reboot) and for help `openfiles /local /?`. After rebooting `openfiles /query`.

Comment: BTW open files can be renamed. The old way of replacing files was to rename it, replace it with the new file, and then reboot. Windows uses the old file till rebooting then the new one.